# Python string replace blackslash w character

Tags: python-3.x, replace

I'm trying to perform string replace that contain backsplash with a character. Any able to guide how to handle backsplash with a character

```
string= 'decimal("\t",0) Amount = 0;'
print(string.replace('\t','\0'))  #tried: print(string.replace('"\\t"','"\\0"'))
```

expected output

```
decimal("\0",0) Amount = 0;
```

current output

```
decimal("   ",0) Amount = 0;
```

Comment: Have you tried `replace('\t', '\\0')`?

Comment: Thanks your solution worked on the terminal, but when I tried replacing within a file old string kept evolution as tab.. with minor mod it worked `replace('\\t', '\\0')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given:

```
>>> string= 'decimal("\t",0) Amount = 0;'
```

You can use the literal `\` with `'\\'` and do:

```
>>> print(string.replace('\t','\\0'))
decimal("\0",0) Amount = 0;
```

Careful not to confuse what is printed with its interpreter representation which will be the double backslash form:

```
>>> string.replace('\t','\\0')
'decimal("\\0",0) Amount = 0;'
```

Also understand that `'\t'` is a single character; a tab. The character `'\0'` is also a single character; a `NUL`:

```
>>> len('\t')
1
>>> len('\0')
1
```

What you need is the two character string `'\\0'` which in turn will be printed as `'\0'` even though that is not a `NUL`:

```
>>> len('\\0')
2
>>> '\\0'=='\0'
False
```

As an alternative to `'\\0'` you can also use a raw string:

```
>>> '\\0'==r'\0'
True
```

Which you use is a matter of preference (I use the `r` form exclusively for regex for example and personally prefer `\\` for applications like this) but it is a form you should know.

Comment: Note: Raw string literals can be used as an alternative to all the double-escaping. Doesn't matter much for literals describing a single character, but it's arguably clearer that you intend the string to be interpreted "as is". For instance, instead of `'\\0'`, you can do `r'\0'` (note `r` immediately preceding open quote).

Comment: Thanks guys above info very helpful. `print(string.replace('\t','\\0'))` helped while printing in terminal. When implementing in for loop inside file open  `replace('\\t', '\\0')` worked

Comment: @Qzia88: The discrepancy indicates your file had a literal backslashes followed by `t`, where the string literals you were using didn't match (because you used `\t` in a non-raw string literal, so it became the tab character). When testing, I'd suggest using raw strings for the strings you define in your code, as it will visually match the data seen in the file you're reading.